# Plotting predicted MSE as a function of the training sample size for choosing $K$ in $K$-fold CV

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, data-mining

From *Principles and Theory for Data Mining and Machine Learning*, Clarke et al.:

> One strategy for choosing $K$, if enough data are available, is to plot the predicted MSE as a function of the size of the training sample. Once the curve levels off, there is no need to increase the size of the portion of the data used for fitting. Thus, the complement gives the size of the holdout portion, and dividing $n$ by this gives an estimate of the optimal $K$.

I don't understand this.

MSE is dependent on the training sample and test sample: training sample is used to build the model, test sample is used for the points for the MSE comparison.

So if I want to choose a training sample of, say, 5 from some large data set, 
obviously, the MSE I compute will be dependent on what points I choose and not solely the training sample size. So that makes me wonder, how in the world would I compute that curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only having few samples in the training set it is easier for the model to find a fit/representation of the data with few error - so the resulting training error will usually be lower than with using more samples. In this state, the training samples *under-represent* the complexity of the real data, hence the resulting fit will usually not generalize well.

In contrast, if you increase the amount of samples, finding a correct fit/representation of the training samples will usually become harder, thereby increasing the training error. But this also leads to a better generalization, as the representation becomes more realistic (thereby reducing the test error). If you try different training set sizes and compare the corresponding training and test error, you will usually end up with a curve similar to this one:

[image: Training and test error over nr. of training samples.]

In the figure, training error is purple and evaluation error (denoted CV) is pink.

The same mechanism applies to CV and seems to be used for determining the $K$ in the example you mentioned in your question. In case 50% of data are enough to achieve a suitable fit, 2-fold CV would be enough. In contrast, 90% training data would require a 10-fold CV instead. You would thereby see the training error cure flattening out the same way as in the figure above.

How to obtain such a plot (slow, stable):

1. Use different $K$ and preserve both the corresponding $K$ associated training and $K$ test errors.
2. Plot the average/median/etc. training and test error over $K$.

What I assume the authors suggested (much faster, but less stable):

1. Do a simple train/test split of your data, fit your model and preserve the training and test error.
2. At first, do point 1 with a small portion of data in your training partition, then increase the training partition continuously. Preserve all associated training and test errors and plot them over the training partition size.
3. As soon as the curve flattens out (will usually not be easy to determine) you know how big the portion of the data to use for training your model will be, and can therefore derive the required amount of partitions (e.g. using 80% of data in the training partition would correspond to having a 5-fold CV).

(PS: I'm sure that there are better figures than the one I just used, right here on CV, so anyone knowing such: feel free to replace it!)

Comment: I get the intuition and everything, but I'm particularly interested in *how* the curve would be computed.

Comment: @Clarinetist OK, I don't know what the $n$ in the citation in your question refers to exactly, but I've updated my answer to (very shortly) state how I'd obtain such a plot. If this is not what you were asking for please let me know.

Comment: $n$ refers to the size of the random sample. $K$-fold cross validation requires setting $\ell K = n$, where $\ell$ is the common size of the subsamples.

Comment: `Plot the average/median/etc. training and test error over $K$.` This is what I suspected and all I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @Clarinetist OK! I'm still not completely sure if the authors didn't instead mean to repeatedly use a simple train/test split, thereby increase the training partition size, and plot the resulting training error over training partition size. This would be faster and still valid, but of course more unstable, as you only use a single result each time. But the core idea would be the same: you would see the training error going up and (hopefully) flattening out.